# Append parameters to URL

Tags: node.js, express, axios

How can we append the parameters to path URL using axios.get() in react client?

```
axios.get('/api/order/user/', {
params: {
    user_id: 2
}
})
```

the route defined in the express server is this.

```
router.route('/user/:user_id').get(//);
```

This is what return from the above axios.get() code.
GET /api/order/user/?user_id=2

What I want to achieve is something like this.
GET /api/order/user/2

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to achieve is `path parameter`

```
const url = '/api/order/user/' + user_id;
axios.get(url);
```

The `params` property in `axios` is `Query parameter`
GET /api/order/user/?user_id=2

Comment: Works fine now. Thank you. :)